# Synchronise a directory with another directory

Tags: centos, directory, synchronization

I have a problem that requires a directory `/home/me/devstuff` to regularly be updated with contents from another directory `/media/shared_folder/devstuff`.

The contents of the `/home/me/devstuff` should be overwritten with contents of `/media/shared_folder/devstuff` every 2 minutes, and size of the directories will be about ~100MB.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: Hi, @WissamAl-Roujoulah, at the moment I'm just manually removing the `/home/me/devstuff` and copying the `/media/shared_folder/devstuff` to the destination. Doing the whole thing with one command is almost convenient but I'm trying to automate it to be run every couple minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rsync`:

```
rsync -az /media/shared_folder/devstuff /home/me/devstuff
```

So all you need to do is to set up a cron job to run this command every 2 minutes:

```
*/2 * * * *   /usr/bin/rsync -az /media/shared_folder/devstuff /home/me/devstuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the `--delete` argument with `rsync` if you want to particularly synchronize to a directory, not just copy stuff there. This will keep updating the files in the target directory to keep it an exact copy of the source: if a new file is created in the source, it will appear in the destination directory, if something gets deleted in the source, the same will happen at the destination.
And, of course, as the others have already mentioned here, use the built-in automation software: `cron`